# Installing numpy on Windows7 having Python 3.4

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I want to install numpy on my Windows 7.I have python 3.4 already installed on the machine.

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

For some reason the python shell says `win32`. what does this mean? I heard that you need to have 32-bit python for numpy to be installed.

Comment: `I heard that you need to have 32-bit python for numpy to be installed.` - Your source appears to be untrustworthy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says AMD64, so you have 64-bit Python.  You don't need 32-bit Python.  In some cases it can be tough to find Windows installers for 64-bit Python libraries.  However, in many cases (including Numpy) you can get the libraries you need for 64-bit Python on Windows from [Christoph Gohlke's incredibly useful site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).